# Не получается сделать задачу на python

Tags: python

На входе случайные натуральные числа в массиве [40]
Запрашиваете у пользователя натуральное число.
На выходе сформировать массив только из тех чисел, которые стояли рядом и сумма этих чисел равна числу которое ввел пользователь.При этом повторяться элементы не должны из основного массива.
Пример:пользователь вводит 10
Подходящая последовательность:9+1 = 10; 1+9=10; 5+5=10
Ожидаемый вывод: [9,1,9,5,5]

Вот моя наработка, но у меня не выводит так как должно быть по условию

```
mass = []
allNum = [2, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5]
FindNumSumm = 10
Nums = False

for i in range( 1, len(allNum) ):
    if allNum[i-1] + allNum[i] == FindNumSumm:
        if not(Nums):
            mass.append(allNum[i-1])
        mass.append(allNum[i])
        allNum = True
    else:
        Nums = False
print(mass)
```

Comment: Вам точно нужно уничтожить весь массив `allNum` и привести его к булеву?

Comment: В вашей последовательности нет таких двух цифр подряд, которые при сложении дают 10.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте `allNum = True` на `Nums = True` и дайте на вход такую последовательность, чтобы из неё можно было набрать нужную сумму. Сейчас в вашей последовательности нет подходящих слагаемых, чтобы в сумме получилось 10.